# Python get json array item by matching value

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have an array of json data that looks like this:

```
[{
  "first_name": "Joe",
  "last_name": "Smith",
  "numbers": [1,2,3,4,5]
}, {
  "first_name": "Jane",
  "last_name": "Doe",
  "numbers": [6,4,1,35,2]
}, {
  "first_name": "Mike",
  "last_name": "Everyman",
  "numbers": [8,5,3,2,4,5]
}]
```

How can I select just the array item where last_name = Doe? I am trying to convert some code I wrote in ruby to python since lambda doesn't support ruby :(
My ruby code looks like:

```
match = data.select {|x| x[:last_name] == 'Doe'}
```

Which returns:

```
{
 "first_name": "Jane",
 "last_name": "Doe",
 "numbers": [6,4,1,35,2]
}
```

Also, I know that wouldn't technically work in ruby since the data is in json form, but I converted it from a hash to json and don't feel like changing it back cause the base idea is still the same.

Comment: I was trying to figure this out off of that question, but the filtered answer was giving me some weird object type that I couldn't figure out how to get my data out of.  Specifically: `TypeError: 'filter' object is not subscriptable`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a generator expression, calling `next` on it to supply the first matching item if any:

```
match = next(d for d in data if d['last_name'] == 'Doe')
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed.  Simple and to the point! Thanks much.